# How to implement a rest method that accepts a user-defined type

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee

I have created a REST method in Java EE and I have a lot of parameters to send to this method.
There for, I don't want to accept them as primitive params, but as one user-defined object that contain all the fields.

How can I do that? I couldn't find any example.

I couldn't find any example.

I would like to have something like that:

```
@Path(value = "/First")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyController extends BaseController {
@POST
@Path("/SaveDetails")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseMap SaveDetails(MyData myData) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With native java you need to convert json string to java object.. You can change your `MyData` type to `String` and convert string to mydata with a json converter. If you use jacson library you can convert it with ObjectMapper class

Comment: how does the Java EE know to send the whole json request inside that String

Comment: Java EE will put the post request body to your string variable. You will know this string variable is json object.